# Using gcp-types/servicenetworking.googleapis.com:services.connections in google cloud's deployment manager

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-platform

Can you tell me how you run the deployment manager with gcp-types/servicenetworking.googleapis.com:services.connections? I tried gcloud alpha too but I'm getting an error like this:

```
- code: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
  message: The provider servicenetworking.googleapis.com at project gcp-types was
    not found in public GCP types
```

code:

```
 - name: peering
   action: gcp-types/servicenetworking.googleapis.com:services.connections
   properties:
     network: projects/$(ref.project.projectId)/global/networks/$(ref.vpc.name)
     reservedPeeringRanges:
       - {{ properties['range'] }}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this @Kenji Yonekawa?